# C# Parent form open child form, call child function after parent closes

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

To cut a long story short...
I need Form_1 to open Form_2.
I need Form_2 to execute code, AFTER Form_1 has been hidden.
(without user interation)

At the moment, my Form_1 code is thus....

```
function myFunction(){
// Create a new instance of the child form class
   Form2 F2 = new Form2(this,d);
// Minimise current form
  this.Hide();
// Show the child form
  F2.Show();
}
```

F2.Show then initiates further code from Form2_Shown event.

Problem is that I need the Form2_Shown code to run after Form1 has completely hidden.
Because Form1.myFunction calls F2.Show(), then Form2_Shown will allways occur whilst Form1 is not 'retired' completely.

Is there a way to seperate this chain of events to get the desired outcome?
Open Form_2
Close Form_1
Run code in Form_2 with no remaining connections to Form_1 ?

Threads ?? (he says in ignroance of them)

And before you ask ... this is for a screen capture application.
Form_1 is the UI with buttons.
Form_2 is a fullscreen transparent form.
Because Form_1 is hanging in there, it causes black images.

If I use the same model, but trigger the screen capture off of a keypress in Form_2, then everything works perfectly.

Hope that makes sense.
I can of course post reams of code, if required.

Many Thanks.

Comment: So create an event in the `Form1` class, and have `Form2` subscribe to that event. When `Form1` is hidden, it fires the event.

Comment: Have you tried showing Form2 on the `VisibleChanged` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in a reference to Form1 in Form2's constructor. Then from the constructor of Form2 call the Form1.Hide() method. Then, from Form2's constructor call the Show() method on Form2.